# Back arrow in toolbar slide animation isn't working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, animation

I have a problem. When I'm in my `MainActivity.java` and calling the `SettingsActivity.java` the slide animation is working. But unfortunately when I'm clicking at the back arrow the slide animation isn't working. I hope you can help me! Thank you in advance!

**MainActivity.java**

```
 Intent intentAccess = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SettingsActivity.class);
 startActivity(intentAccess);
 overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
```

**slide_in_right.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0" />
</set>
```

**slide_out_left.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="-100%p" />
</set>
```

**SettingsActivity.xml**

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**SettingAcitvity.java**

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
   <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"></activity>
```

Comment: Attach code when you handle back in SettingsActivity

Comment: @CôngHải sure! Please see the edit. Thanks for the comment I forgot it.

Comment: did you forgot call finish before call overridePendingTransition?

Comment: Quite possible maybe! I hope you can help me.

Comment: switch(item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
    }

Comment: not sure you using Toolbar or not, try it

Comment: @CôngHải worked! :) Thank you very much!!

Comment: But the last problem it is not smooth like the settings button. :(

Comment: You should create new 2 animations slide_out_right and slide_in_left and when you press back button you should call overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right)

Comment: @CôngHải please add this to your answer! Thanks!  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="100%p" />
</set>`

Comment: Actually you can update to your question, my answer just solve about when back button not animated :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SettingActivity you should change `onOptionsItemSelected` to this

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) { 
        case android.R.id.home: 
           finish(); 
           overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
    } 
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```